How to numerically calculate jacobian matrix
I'm having trouble figuring out how to programmatically construct the Jacobian matrix for a PDE. Take for example a 1D (ODE):
$$f(u,x)=\frac{\partial ^2 u}{\partial x^2} +\pi^2 \sin{(\pi x)}=0$$
I want to construct the Jacobian matrix $$\frac{\partial f_i}{\partial u_j},$$ where say for a given discretised domain $x$ I can use finite difference to solve for $u$ and therefore $f$. So in this case if I have $n$ discretised points for $x$, my jacobian should be of size $n$ by $n$, and my $f$ and $u$ are both of size $1$ by $n$.
How do I then go about constructing the Jacobian? Is each term something like $(f_{i+1}-f_i)/(u_{j+1}-u_j)$? I am a bit confused over this simple question.

$u$ is presumably a function of $x$, right? In which case, $f$ is a function that takes as input a function and a scalar. What would a Jacobian be for such an $f$?

The definition of a Jacobian I'm familiar with requires a function $f : \mathbb{R}^m \to \mathbb{R}^n$. Your $f$ doesn't appear to fit this description.
